# UIImagePickerController got white screen after returning from a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is the situation:

After taking a picture from

```
[UIImagePickerController takePicture];
```

The following delegate function :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

will be called.

The code inside is

```
NSLog(@"Photo taken");
UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
NSLog(@"Width: %d, Height: %d ",(int)newImage.size.width, (int)newImage.size.height);
//[imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
ProcessCompleteView *pcv = [[ProcessCompleteView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcessCompleteView" bundle:nil];
[imagePickerController presentModalViewController:pcv animated:YES];
[pcv release];
```

I've called another view to display sth and when I return back from pcv using **dismissModalViewController**, the area which should display the camera's real-time capture turns white. However, when I dismiss the **UIImagePickerController** and present it again, the camera works fine!

Anyone can help me on this strange issue??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The order to show view is incorrect.

The correct order is:
parent controller's view show -> UIImagePickerController's view show -> UIImagePickerController's view hidden -> ProcessCompleteView show

So, please remove

```
ProcessCompleteView *pcv = [[ProcessCompleteView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcessCompleteView" bundle:nil];
[imagePickerController presentModalViewController:pcv animated:YES];
[pcv release];
```

into parent controller's viewWillAppear method, and call

```
ProcessCompleteView *pcv = [[ProcessCompleteView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcessCompleteView" bundle:nil];
[parentController presentModalViewController:pcv animated:YES];
[pcv release];
```